# C pass void pointer array to function

Tags: c, void-pointers

I want to pass a void pointer array to a function which fills it with the result it works fine with `integer` but I have troubles returning `char*`

```
int function(void *arr[]);
int main(void) {
    void *arr[3];
    function(arr);
    printf("%d\n", *(int *)&arr[0]);
    printf("%d\n", *(int *)&arr[1]);
    printf("%s\n", (char *)&arr[2]);
}
int function(void *arr[]){
    arr[0] = (void*)(int)4;
    arr[1] = (void*)(int)6;
    char* test = "abc";
    arr[2] = (void*)test;
    return 0;
}
```

for the String I don't get the right value

Comment: "I want to pass a void pointer array to a function which fills it with the result" - **why?!**

Comment: `integer` isn't a type, and `sizeof(int)` is not necessarily `sizeof(void*)`.

Comment: @Dai this is just a example, I want to pass a sql string to a function and the sql defines how many result values I get.

Comment: What on earth does SQL have to do with abusing `void*`?

Comment: I thought void* would be the best way to return a not defined number of results?

Comment: What database library are you using? Implementations of ODBC will include their own types to represent unbound results.

Comment: But more importantly, why are you using SQL from within C? C is not meant for applications programming.

Comment: I use `sqlite`, I had to use C (university project)

Comment: Sorry, but that's not possible, at least not in the way you think it is. Where should the _actual integers_ be stored? Where do you reserve memory for `3` `int`s? Doing `arr[0] = (void*)(int)4;` followed by `*(int *)&arr[0]` is invalid - there is no `int*` pointer there, you can't dereference it, `&arr[0]` is a `void **`.

Comment: @KamilCuk makes sense, but for the integers it actually works!

Comment: You are coding in a language with [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). "Works" has actually little to do with correctness of the code. You may just `(int)arr[0]` and it will also "work" and also be correct.

Comment: @user2071938 It only works for you because *on your computer* `sizeof(int) <= sizeof(void*)`. That is definitely not true on other computers - and for example, if you try to store a `__int128` value your program definitely won't work.

Comment: `printf("%s\n", (char *)&arr[2]);` does not attempt to print the string that `arr[2]` points to. It attempts to print the contents of `arr[2]` as a string. This is because it does not pass the address that is the **value** of `arr[2]` to `printf`; it passes the **address** of `arr[2]` to `printf`, and, for `%s`, `printf` attempts to pass the string at the address it is given. But `arr[2]` is a pointer, and we should not expect the bytes representing it to appear as a sensible string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may pass an array of `void`s, and assign that array elements to a dynamically allocated memory region that stores the pointed-to value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int function(void *arr[]){    
    arr[0] = malloc(sizeof(int));
    if (arr[0] == NULL) goto ERR_MALLOC_0;
    *(int*)arr[0] = 4;

    arr[1] = malloc(sizeof(int));
    if (arr[1] == NULL) goto ERR_MALLOC_1;
    *(int*)arr[1] = 6;

    const char *const test = "abc";
    arr[2] = malloc(strlen(test));
    if (arr[2] == NULL) goto ERR_MALLOC_2;
    strcpy(arr[2], test);

    return 0;

    // remember about error checking
    free(arr[2]);
    ERR_MALLOC_2:
    free(arr[1]);
    ERR_MALLOC_1:
    free(arr[0]);
    ERR_MALLOC_0:
    return -1;
}

int main(void) {
    void *arr[3];
    int err = function(arr);
    if (err == -1) abort();

    // & is the address of element, not it's element
    printf("%d\n", *(int*)arr[0]);
    printf("%d\n", *(int*)arr[1]);
    printf("%s\n", (char*)arr[2]);

    // remember to free memory
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        // funny how we do not need to know the effective type
        free(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

But such function is just plainly confusing and will result in many, many bugs and problems. Instead just actually use variables of proper type:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int function(int *val1, int *val2, char **string) {
    *val1 = 3;
    *val2 = 6;
    const char *test = "abc";
    *string = malloc(strlen(test));
    if (*string == NULL) return -1;
    strcpy(*string, test);
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    int val1; 
    int val2;
    char *string;
    int err = function(&val1, &val2, &string);
    if (err == -1) abort();

    printf("%d\n", val1);
    printf("%d\n", val2);
    printf("%s\n", string);

    free(string);
}
```

If you are really striving for implementing some virtual representation and operations on different data types, using plain "array of `void` pointers" will get you nowhere, because such array doesn't know what is the underlying type of the value that is being stored - you, as a programmer, have to know what is inside that array (ie. that `arr[0]` is an `int` and `arr[2]` is a `char*`), so as you know it you might as well just use variables of proper types from the start.

Comment: "so as you know it you might as well just use variables of proper types from the start." - and when you don't you need to use a tagged-union type.

Comment: Thank you!
maybe I go with array of `int*` and array of `char*` because those are the only types I need. But the number of results for each type is not defined.

Comment: `and when you don't you need to use a tagged-union type` as would an intermediate programmer do, which results in what I call [big fat switched](https://github.com/Gurux/GuruxDLMS.c/blob/master/development/src/gxset.c#L48), which are hard to maintain, reason about and very hard to refactor. A way [better design](https://linux-kernel-labs.github.io/refs/heads/master/labs/device_drivers.html#struct-file-operations)  that will last for years is creating an interface with proper [dispatch table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispatch_table). Anyway, design always depends.

Answer (score 2):

`arr` has type `void(*)[3]`.

`arr[0]` has type `void*`. The fact that it stores a suitably converted value of `4` is irrelevant.

`&arr[0]` has type `void**`.

`(int *)&arr[0]` has type `int*`, but it points to an object of type `void*` instead of pointing to an object of type `int`. This is not what pointers normally do. You *can* have such a pointer, but the **only** thing you can legally do with it is convert it back to the right type, in this case `void**`. You are not doing that.

`*(int *)&arr[0]` has type `int`.

Here you are accessing an object of type `void*` through an lvalue of type `int`. This is undefined behaviour. Don't do that.

If you want to convert `arr[0]` back to `int`, just do that:

```
printf("%d\n", (int)arr[0]);
```

Likewise, if you want to convert `arr[2]` back to `char*`, do just that:

```
printf("%s\n", (char*)arr[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr[0] = (void*)(int)4;
```

The above line cast the integer 4 as void pointer (address) and stores it in the array `arr` as pointer address. I guess that's not what you wanted.

In order to access data using a void pointer the way you want, first make it point to a valid memory address, which will hold the data when the function exits. You have to be careful while assigning memory address to a void pointer inside a function, all variables in that function's stack (local variables) will be popped off the from the stack when the function exits, making that memory addresses invalid. Only use static (or global) or dynamic memory while assigning the memory address to your pointer inside the function, if you want to use it outside the function.